# How to change cursor on iFrame "Select File"

Tags: html, iframe, css

I am using an iFrame to simulate an `<input type="file">`. Here is what it does:

1 - A link shows that says `"Choose your file"`.

2 - A user clicks the link, browses a file on their local computer.

3 - When a user selects the file, it starts uploading automatically.

This is working great. However,I am unable to control the type of cursor. How would I force the cursor to be a pointer?

http://jsfiddle.net/4paY6/ is an example of the below code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .attach-file:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .attach-file {
            padding-left: 22px;
            background: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}images/new/attach-file.png") no-repeat 0 1px;
            color: #0BA5D9;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        form {
            float: right;
        }
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        input[type="file"] {
            z-index: 999;
            opacity: 0.0; 
            line-height: 0; 
            position: absolute;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 500px; 
            top: -100px; 
            left: -200px;

            -moz-appearance: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
            cursor: pointer;
            -moz-binding: none;
        }

        input[type="file"] > input[type="text"] {
          border-color: inherit;
          background-color: inherit;
          color: inherit;
          font-size: inherit;
          height: inherit;
        }

        /* button part of file selector */
        input[type="file"] > input[type="button"] {
            height: inherit;
            font-size: inherit;
        }
        input[type="file"]:hover {
            cursor: default;
        }
        * {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: inline">
        <label style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
           <span class="attach-file">Attach File</a>
            <input type="file" name="attachment" />
        </label>
    </form>
</body>
```

What do I need to add or change for the above to simulate a cursor in Firefox when hovering over the iFrame?

Comment: You need to fix the html code, open the `<a>` tag and close the `</span>` tag

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that, though the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS

```
input[type="file"]:hover {
        cursor: default;
    }
```

is overriding the other style definitions.  Remove it, and you get the pointer cursor.

Comment: There was an answer (since delete) that said if you set the opacity to 1 you can see what's going on. I did that, and the Firefox file input field is like a text box, and when you click it it opens the browse file dialogue. The above doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... viewing your JSFiddle in IE9, I see the exact same behavior just with different cursors by removing the line mentioned.  I have to double-click in both cases to activate the file open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the opacity back to 1 you can see what the problem is - the input takes up the whole page. If you change the height to 0px it seems to work as expected. Note that your span tag is not closed properly (you have </a> instead of </span>)

Comment: Right it will 'work' in that it will display correct, but the action won't trigger at all. So it will look nice but have zero function.

Comment: I haven't looked in great detail about how you are doing it, but if you make that change and click the link, the attach file dialog displays.

Comment: The functionality does work because both the span and input are inside a label - clicking on the span is therefore the same as clicking on the input. In fact it looks like you can just put display:none on the input and still have the functionality. That way you don't need to both with opacity or trying to move it off the page.